# How can I restore using systemback when not booting (and without iso)

Tags: boot, data-recovery, systemback

I've been trying to change some configurations and now my ubuntu gets stuck in the loading page when starting. Even when I try to start using the safe mode it freezes...
I had recently made a back up using systemback (not the iso) and can access the folder using the boot disc. Is there any  way that I can recover my system using these systemback files from the disc (or using dual boot)??

Comment: Or is there a way of using this folder to make a bootable disc???

Answer (score 1):

First, try to boot the system in normal mode. Wait a little and try to switch to tty1 with Ctrl+Alt+F1. If possible, then login and using *systemback-cli* command to perform a system restoration.
If the restoration is not possible, you need to boot an other system. Install the Systemback and perform a system repair. Just set the storage directory, select a restore point and mount the partitions.

Comment: Thank you. That was kinda helpful. Actually I couldn't even access the tty1, so I had to reinstall the system, then reinstall systemback and only then restore.